# Handle client events in Asp.net AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an Asp.net AJAX control and in client control class I want to handle the onFocus event for some textboxes in my control.  I would like to have only one handler for all the textboxes, however in the handler I don't know how to get the source element that caused the focus event.

In my initialize function I will have the following code for each text box:

```
this._onfocusFunctionDelegate = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onFocus);
$addHandler(this._textBox1, 'focus', this._onfocusFunctionDelegate);  //repeated for each textbox
```

in the _onFocus handler I want to be able to determine which textbox fired the event and call select() for that textbox.

```
_onFocus: function(evt) {
// how do I get the source element?  The following doesn't work
evt.srcElement.select(); }
```

So how do I figure out what element fired the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by accessing the event object and using the target property.  On MSDN I was only able to find references to srcElemnt, but found target mentioned much more on the web.  Trying target solved the issue.  If anyone can find documentation backing this up I would appreciate a pointer to it.